# Quick One regarding Margins and Storyboards

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

Just a quick question, I've been searching for ages on Google. I have a storyboard:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="ViewLeftToRight" AccelerationRatio=".5" DecelerationRatio=".5">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ReferenceInfo" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:0.15" To="{Binding, Width},0,0,0"/>
</Storyboard>
```

It doesn't work. I was wondering if there is a way for me to bind the Width of the control to the "left" margin. If I need to use a converter, could you possibly show how it would be written in XAML in the above example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't bind an animation to `Margin`, because it does not define a corresponding dependency property.  There are several alternatives, here are two:

1. Place your object in a Canvas and animate `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`
2. Define a `RenderTransform` on your object, and animate its `X` and `Y` properties.

---

### 1)

```
<Canvas>
    <TextBlock Text="test" x:Name="ReferenceInfo" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" />
</Canvas>
```

Here your storyboard short target the same element `ReferenceInfo`, but target the *attached properties*, which you denote using brackets like "(Canvas.Left)":

```
<DoubleAnimation 
    Storyboard.TargetName="ReferenceInfo" 
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Duration="0:0:0.15" 
    To="{Binding Width}"/>
```

### 2)

```
<TextBlock Text="test" x:Name="ReferenceInfo">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="TranslateReferenceInfo" X="0" Y="0" />
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
```

The animation would then reference the `TranslateTransform` itself by name:

```
<DoubleAnimation 
    Storyboard.TargetName="TranslateReferenceInfo" 
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Duration="0:0:0.15" 
    To="{Binding Width}"/>
```